# A diagram of P. Coleman's Introduction to Many-Body Physics

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, superconductivity, many-body

In the book Piers Coleman - Introduction to Many-Body Physics in page 548,

> The renormalization of the Coulomb interaction can be understood as the screening
> effect of high-frequency virtual pair fluctuations on energy scales between $\omega_D$ and the
> bandwidth $D$. Whereas pair fluctuations enhance an attractive interaction, they screen a
> repulsive interaction, driving it logarithmically towards weak coupling at low energies.
> The renormalized Coulomb interaction can be written self-consistently as follows:
> [image]
> where $\mu$ is a dimensionless coupling constant representing the Fermi surface average of the Coulomb interaction, and $\mu^*$ is the screened Coulomb pseudopotential,
> $$\mu^*=\frac{\mu}{1+\mu \ln(D/\omega_D)} $$
> Here $D$ is the bandwith and $\omega_D$ is the phonon frequency.

My question is How Coleman writes the last diagram in algebra representation, especially the term in the midd $1/2|\epsilon_k|$? Using Feynman rules, this should product of electron propagator,

$$\sum_k\frac{1}{i\omega_n-\epsilon_{k}}\frac{1}{i\omega_n-\epsilon_{-k}}$$